# Retrieve All Subscriber Status

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, custom-profile, ssjs

I am working on a custom profile center and I'm using server side javascript to extract information about the lists a subscriber is currently subscribed to.  When I use the lists.retrieve function it successfully pulls out all the lists that a subscriber is on except for the All Subscriber list.  I am working on an enterprise 2.0 account and I'm operating in one of the business units and our settings are established so that when a subscriber unsubscribes from all communications they unsubscribe from only the business unit.  
What I need is a way to retrieve a subscriber's status on the All Subscribers List so I can accurately portray their status on my profile center.  
I can do this with either SSJS or AmpScript if anyone knows a method in one language or the other.

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 5):

These days you can use the WSProxy to achieve what you need here. Run at parent level BU.

```
<script  runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var id = '1234abc'; //subscriber key
var queryAllAccounts = true; // this is important otherwise you just get the parent BU
var cols = ["Status","Client.ID"];
var filter = {
    Property: "SubscriberKey",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: id
};
var desc = prox.retrieve("Subscriber", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts);
// desc.Results will be an array of... results.
</script>
```

Comment: This is the first time I've come across this WSProxy - you're a lifesaver!  I'm dealing with 38x Business Units and needed to obtain the PublicationList Names in each one!

Answer (score 3):

Because its an Enterprise 2.0 account, you can do the following, using the subscriber system view (see more info at [Data View: Subscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/)):

```
%%[
    var @name       
    SET @name = "dude@exacttarget.com"

    SET @status= Lookup("_subscribers", "status" , "EmailAddress", @name)

]%%
```

----- New EXAMPLE-----

Something I have using AMPscript in a clients code... may be useful here

```
        SET @rr2 = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
        SetObjectProperty(@rr2,"ObjectType","Subscriber")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "ID")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "EmailAddress")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "SubscriberKey")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "Status")

        /* Create a filter be the subscriber Id */
        SET @sfp2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
        SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"Property","SubscriberKey")
        SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"SimpleOperator","equals")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp2,"Value",@email)

        /* invoke the Retrieve Call */
        SetObjectProperty(@rr2,"Filter",@sfp2)
        SET @atts = InvokeRetrieve(@rr2,@status)
```

Then I loop through the results

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this isn't working for me. I have it on my landing page and it isn't returning a value for me. I'm also confused about the link you provided. You sent over the query activity data view but you are using ampscript. Can you use ampscript functions with the query data views?

Comment: The link was for the purpose of showing the data views exposed, nothing more.  You cannot use ampscript with query activities, although that would be interesting for sure. You may also try the SSJS found here (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/server_side_javascript_sample_code/ scroll to Retrieving Lists from an Account)   Can you post your exact code?

Comment: %%[

set @status = Lookup("_Subscribers", "Status" , "EmailAddress", "jakefieldm89@test.com")
]%%

Comment: %%[
set @sk = [_subscriberkey]
]%%
<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");
var sk = Variable.GetValue("@sk");

var subObj = Subscriber.Init(sk);
var attributes = subObj.Lists.Retrieve();
var attributesLength = attributes.length;
Write(Stringify(attributes));

for (var i = 0; i < attributesLength; i++) {
 var listid = attributes[i].List.ID;
 if (listid == "17522427") {
  var status = attributes[i].Status;
  Variable.SetValue("kicksub",status);
 }
 else  {
 }
}
</script>

Comment: Ok I posted my attempt at what you sent me and then I posted the javascript I was trying to utilize.  The listid in the javascript is the all subscribers listid for the business unit but as I said that isn't a recognized list when I execute this function.

Comment: What kind of permissions does your user have?  When you log in to the application, can you  navigated to the all subs list?

Comment: I have admin privileges so I can do anything within the account.

Comment: Is there any solution to pull out all subscriber list from the child account to check the subscribers?